# Lua os.date script error

Tags: lua

The below script is giving error.
Can you suggest how to solve it?

```
if os.date("%H:%M")>21:00 and os.date("%H:%M")<06:30  
then MV.110 = 1

else MV.110 = 0

end
```

The error is:

```
input:1: 'then' expected near ':'
```

Comment: Can you post there error you get?

Comment: error:           input:1: 'then' expected near ':'

Comment: The error message needs to be in the question (I've added it for you).

Answer (score 3):

you have two syntax errors in your code. the first is the issue that `os.date` returns the date/time as a string and you're attempting to compare that against some bare word values. at a minimum wrap `21:00` and `06:30` in quotes to compare string values (probably not what you want). you can call os.date with the special value `'*t'` to get the time back in a table format so you can compare hours/minutes/seconds in integer values.

your next issue will be that 110 isn't a valid property name for a table since variable/property names can't start with a number in lua. if you really wanted to use 110 as the key for the value in the table, you'll have use it as an index into the table like this: `MV['110'] = 1`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the issues pointed out in [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34183850/827263), you have a logical error.

The kind of comparison you're doing can work if you compare strings. `"21:00"` is a valid string; `21:00` without the quotation marks is simply a syntax error.

The relational operators (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`) can be applied to strings. The comparison is done lexicographically, so `"abc" < "def"`, and `"123" > "0234"`. (It's not a numeric comparison, so you need to be consistent with leading zeros -- which `os.date("%H:%M")` does for you.)

But even if you change your code so it compares strings:

```
if os.date("%H:%M") > "21:00" and os.date("%H:%M") < "06:30" then
...
```

it's not going to work, since there is no string that is both greater than `"21:00"` and less than `"06:30"`.

You haven't quite said what you're trying to do, but I can assume you want to check whether the current time is within the 9-hour interval between 21:00 and 06:30.  The problem is that the interval crosses midnight, so a simple comparison won't work.

You need to check whether the string is greater than `"21:00"` **or** less than `"06:30"`. (I haven't actually tested this logic, so you should.)

Also, you should save the result of `os.date("%H:%M")` in a variable. If you call it twice, there's a possibility that it could return different results; the first call might return `"21:00"` and the second `"21:01"`. In this particular case it probably wouldn't cause any problems, but it's a good idea to be careful anyway.